# Is the sum of positive divergent series always divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

If two positive terms series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ are divergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n+b_n)$ is also divergent.

I thought is was obvious, but I saw a counterexample of this problem, that is, $a_n = n, b_n  = -n.$ However, this is a little bit strange, because $b_n$ is NOT positive terms series.

What's wrong with my thoughts?

Comment: Burning books is  generally not a good advice, but if yours has more such "counterexamples"...

Comment: how is $\sum b_n$ a positive term series?

Comment: what do you think is wrong with your thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both are positive then yes, your thoughts are correct, for example by direct comparison. That example isn't relevant because, as you said, $b_n$ is not a positive sequence.